# Adding Links in UI Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have come across an issue, which is to put a link to another html page into the tab-heading property of the tabset which is included with ui-bootstrap. Here is code of question:

```
 <tabset>
  <tab>
  <tab-heading>
  <a href="link" >Link Page Title
  </a>
  </tab-heading>
  </tab>
  </tabset>
```

However, it seems as if `href` and `<a>` are no longer changing window location to that of the link. I am not looking to modify angular so much, because that would conflict with the controllers I already have -- I know it is improper, but could adding an id to the tab heading and accompanying jquery be a work around?

Comment: "`href` and `<a>` do not work with ui-bootstrap so well", care to explain what doesn't work so well?

Comment: Well, simply they no longer change window location or something of that matter -- it is as if they are now static rather than dynamic. Please do excuse poor terminology, but this is what I can see as the best way to describe it as of now.